# How to get e list of sectors available in IEX cloud

Tags: python, collections, python-requests, request, http-get

I'm using the IEX cloud API and was trying to use the collections filter using a sector specification. For this I need a list of the available sectors. I can get closing prices for S&P 500 stocks. But I want to target all the global mining stocks. Ideally I could use the SIC codes but this is not available as a collection filter.

[Reference documents suggest](https://iexcloud.io/docs/api/#sectors)

```
GET /ref-data/sectors
```

But my python code

```
batch_api_call_url=f'https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable/stock/market/ref-data/sectors&token={IEX_CLOUD_API_TOKEN}' 
data = requests.get(batch_api_call_url)
```

doesn't work.

Any suggestions or references would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you specify what doesn't work? `requests.get()` returns a `request.Response` object, not the actual data. Whats the status code (see `data.status_code`)? Whats the content of the response (see `data.text`)?

Answer (score 1):

The URL appears to be incorrect - it should not contain /stock/market/.

Here is a working request example:

```
batch_api_call_url = f'https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/ref-data/sectors?token={IEX_CLOUD_API_TOKEN}'
data = requests.get(batch_api_call_url)
```